# How to redirect domain with www or without www

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following rewrite rule to redirect domain that has or has not www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It works fine for any sub domain name like `www.domainname.com/abc.php or domainname.com/abc.php`. But not adding `https` in case of `www.domainname.com or domainname.com`.

I tried adding one more rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But, its not working.

Comment: To redirect (say) example.com to www.example.com, add the following code to your .htaccess file. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`   The above code causes the server to check that the domain name portion of the URL is example.com. If it is, the visitor will be sent to www.example.com instead.

Comment: (http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this. Replace example.com with your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```